# ArgumentNullException when streaming files via WCF

Tags: stream, wcf, filestream

I have a WCF streaming binary files. Below is a shortened version of the contract.

```
[MessageContract()]
public class DocumentTransfer
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream Data;
}
```

Everything works fine but there are scenarios when only some other values associated with the file need to be updated but not the file itself. In that case the client sets Data = null. The Data property then cannot be interpreted/serialized and throws this exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.Serialize(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WriteStreamedMessage(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
...UploadDocument(DocumentTransfer request)
...UploadDocument(DocumentTransfer request) in ...
```

**Any ideas guys?**

Comment: Use a different type instead - `DocumentMetadataTransfer`, or something. This is warranted because, as you explain, they fit different purposes. A message only with headers is not exactly a message now, is it? Also, `Title` and `FileName` ought _not_ to be `MessageHeader` items, since they are actually part of the message and aren't necessarily message metadata but rather operation data.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error in SerializeBodyContents when the body is null.

You can either create a different operation for when you do not have a file, or put a byte in the stream to avoid the exception. The first of these options is preferable, the last if you cannot change the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to return Stream.Null.